# Dataweave : Transform XML to JSON

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

Using Mule 4.4 community edition and am using Dataweave to perform transformation.
Payload is in XML as below :

```
    <Result>    
        <TRNO>abcd</TRNO>   
    <EMPS>
        <EMP>
        <NAME>JOHN</NAME>
        <AGE>21</AGE>               
        </EMP>
        <EMP>
        <NAME>TOM</NAME>
        <AGE>18</AGE>               
        </EMP>
    </EMPS>
</Result>
```

I need JSON as below:

```
    {
  "trackId": "abcd",
  "empDetails": [
    {
      "empName": "JOHN",
      "empAge": "21"
    },
    {
      "empName": "TOM",
      "empAge": "18"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to generate using following dataweave but its erroring out :

```
    %dw 2.0
output application/json writeAttributes=true
---
if (payload.Result.EMPS.EMP?)
    "trackId": payload.Result.TRNO,   
    empDetails:payload.Result.EMPS.*EMP map {        
        empName: $.NAME,
        empAge: $.AGE        
    } 

else
null
```

It does not like this line `"trackId": payload.Result.TRNO,` before the array population.
The error is :

> Invalid input ',', expected FieldName (line 5, column 35):
>
> 5|     "trackId": payload.Result.TRNO,
> ^ Location: main (line: 5, column:35)

Answer (score 1):

Just give braces enclosing your if  , should be good.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  writeAttributes=true
---
if (payload.Result.EMPS.EMP?)
  {
    "trackId": payload.Result.TRNO,
    empDetails: payload.Result.EMPS.*EMP map {
      empName: $.NAME,
      empAge: $.AGE
    }
  }
else
  null
```